# Why won't this image load? (This is virtually a hello world program with a simple, local, relative path to the image.)

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to learn HTML and CSS, while working on something off to the side, and just working with files in a folder on my Desktop, the simplest code and the simplest relative path are failing to load a typical jpg.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
    <head>
        <title>some title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img source="some-image.jpg" alt="some text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

This HTML file is in the same folder as some-image, but all that displays is "some text".  I'm using Firefox, and I don't see an option right off the bat to toggle whether it blocks images loaded from a local file path, but I'm running it off my own machine anyway.

One important thing to note is that `styles.css` is having no problem whatsoever loading a background image from pretty much the same directory.

Is this just some security setting related to the local machine?  Is it a coding issue?  What's wrong, and how can it be fixed (without putting down money just yet for a domain or anything)?  And why can the exact same kind of path work just fine when used in a CSS stylesheet?

Comment: Checked the browser console for errors? And what's with `<html xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">`?

Comment: img source="...? Should be img src="...

Comment: @j08691 The site's partially in Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute `source` is not the same as `src`. It should be this:

```
<img src="
```

And not this:

```
<img source="
```

Comment: Thanks.  Kind of embarassing, but I just haven't had much experience with HTML.

Comment: That happens to many people, in fact the "src" if for the "source" and the brain make those things... You are welcome. (And thanks to @JakeGould for the edit)

Answer (score 2):

I made a few simple fixes to the image line for you. Not sure this is all, but they are the fixes i notices at first glance.

Hope this helps!

```
<body>
    <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="some text">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
    <head>
        <title>some title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="some text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Change src in place of source.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/), specifically their [HTML reference pages](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/), to learn the proper usage and properties of the HTML tags you are interested in.

For example, this is in their [<img> tag reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp):

> Example
>
> How to insert an image:
>
> <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">

You can find information there for almost any kind of web development related things, including [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/), [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/), [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) and [more](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how your page should look...**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>    
 <html lang="ja">
       <head>
         <title>Some Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>    
     <body>
      <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="some text" />
    </body> 
</html>
```